# Table body with full screen width

Tags: html, css

I have a table and one `div`, a box for example. How can I make the `thead` to take full width up to that `div` and then make the `tbody` to take the entire screen width? Is this even possible?

[image]

An important aspect is that I must not use fixed values because the table must be responsive.

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vhpw860k/)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="box">
  box
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background:blue;
  color: white;
  float:left;
}
table {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/vhpw860k/1/ ??

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this by creating another empty `th` as the last one, and in every last `td` of your tables rows add `colspan="2"`.

**UPDATE:** wrapped the table and the `.box` div with a container div `.table-container`, set its `position:relative` with `width:100%`, table to extend to fill its container in order to "*make the `tbody` to take the entire screen width*" and assign a `position:absolute` to the `.box` div to position it on the top right corner with `top:0; right:0`. Also removed `float` from the table and the `.box`

[**JS Fiddle** - *updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/vhpw860k/6/)

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.table-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
}
/* no need for table rule here */
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  width: 100px;
}
th:last-child {
  border: none;  /* remove borders from last th */
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td colspan="2">cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td colspan="2">cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td colspan="2">cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="box">
    box
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be a solution, but the thing is that on mobile devices there are some hidden cells placed on last position and they'll become visible on certain situations. Is this the only way for solving this?

Comment: not sure if I understand what you mean, however just forgot to mention that I used `.box{margin-left:-51px;}` to move it backward just for *demonstration purposes*, you probably won't want to do this, you may wrap the table and the `.box` with a container with `position:relative` and set the position of the `.box` to `absolute` with `top:0; right:0`

Comment: @PavelValeriu, check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/vhpw860k/5/, I made a container `.table-container` div to hold the table and the `.box`, removed `float` from table and `.box`, added `position:absolute` to `.box` to position it correctly, hopefully this will work for you

Comment: or this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/vhpw860k/6/ , to "*then make the `tbody` to take the entire screen width?*"